# How to individually lock unordered_map elements in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map` that I want to be accessible by multiple threads but locking the whole thing with a mutex would be too slow.

To get around this I put a mutex in each element of the `unordered_map`:

```cpp
class exampleClass{
    std::mutex m;
    int data;
};

std::unordered_map<int,exampleClass> exampleMap;
```

The issue is I'm unable to safely erase elements, because in order to destroy a mutex it must be unlocked but if it's unlocked then another thread could lock it and be writing to or reading the element during destruction.

Comment: Adding `mutex` to each element only helps you in modifying the element but not erasing it. Erasing element is problematic also because you possibly modify the whole `unordered_map` which may cause interference with other threads that access completely unrelated elements of the `unordered_map` (I am not 100% certain but I believe there is no way to implement it without such property). Generally, if you want to grant read-only to access to different elements you may simply use `shared_mutex`.

Comment: @ALX23z For *any* container, just check if removing an element invalidates iterators and pointers. If it does, not only you need to exclude any access to any other element while you are removing one, but you also need to get access to an element from the container each time you lock the mutex, and not use an existing iterator.

Answer (score 8):

`unordered_map` is not suitable for fine-grained parallelism. It is not legal
to add or remove elements without ensuring mutual exclusion during the process.

I would suggest using something like `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` instead, which will result in less lock contention than locking the map as a whole. (There are other concurrent hash table implementations out there; the advantage of TBB is that it's well-supported and stable.)

Answer (score 1):

@Sneftel's answer is good enough.

But if you insist on using std::unordered_map, I suggest you two use one mutex to protect the insertion/deletion of the map, and another mutex for each element for modifying the element.

```
class exampleClass{
    std::mutex m;
    int data;
};

std::unordered_map<int,exampleClass> exampleMap;
std::mutex mapLock;

void add(int key, int value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(mapLock);
    exampleMap.insert({key, value});
}
void delete(int key) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(mapLock);
    auto it = exampleMap.find(key);
    if (it != exampleMap.end()) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _1(it->m);
        exampleMap.erase(it);
    } 
}
```

These should perform better for a big lock on the whole map if `delete` is not a frequent operation.

But be careful of these kinds of code, because it is hard to reason and to get right.

I strongly recommend @Sneftel's answer.

Comment: If you have a color screen and your eyes (sorry if you have to use a screen reader), you should notice that `delete` appears in blue.

Comment: I can't count the instances where I tried to name a function "register".

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Lock the entire mutex
2. Use a container of shared_ptr so the actual class can be modified (with or without a mutex) unrelated to the container.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr`, in regard to accessing the element it points to, is as thread safe as normal pointer. Meaning - not so much. The only thread safe operationa provided by shared pointer itself are control-block operations.

Comment: @Fureeish the idea was to be able to lock a single element, while at the same time do operations inside the map which would not be affected by the lock if the lock was prohibiting, for example, a copy or a move.

Comment: Then I see no reason to use shated pointer over unique pointer. And we lack context to be sure. However, unique pointer is the default one.